# Putting a variable value into a input's string

Tags: python, variables, input

Is there anyway to have a variable be in the string of an input?

```
score = float(input("Test", grade, "-- Enter score: "))
```

I keep getting:

TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: You have to concatenate using + or format with input. Input is not like print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because the input function received more than 1 argument. It received:

1. "Test"
2. grade
3. "-- Enter score: "

You need to combine those three elements into one, the best way would be using a formatter (%), allowing Python to interpret it as one string:

```
score = float(input("Test %d -- Enter score: " % grade))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 3 strings, should be only one. You're incorrectly concatenating string. Use `format` for that

```
score = float(input("Test {} -- Enter score: ".format(grade)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use % or format to put variable into string:

```
score = float(input("Test %s -- Enter score: " % grade))
```

or

```
score = float(input("Test {} -- Enter score: ".format(grade)))
```